# Get number of gps fix satellites?

Tags: android, gps, lg

I got the GPS_Location:

```
double lo=gps_loc.getLongitude();
double la=gps_loc.getLatitude();
```

I got the Horizontal_Accuracy:

```
int horiAcc=(int)(gps_loc.getAccuracy());
```

I got the HDOP:

```
int hd= (int) (horiAcc/5);
```

But I can't got the number of satellites.

How can I get the number of satellites have been used in my GPS localisation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the GpsStatus Class
it has a method called getMaxSatellites()

if you need further looking into the GPS Satellite Data you can iterate over the List of Satellites with getSatellites()

see:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.html#getMaxSatellites%28%29