# How to get number of available sattelite in android gps

Tags: android, gps, satellite, gps-time

I'm working on GPS in android and I want to show the number of Satellite available at that time for current location and I am getting 3 at all the time in my app while in other app they showing 6 to 9 at same location.I don't know what is the problem.
I am able to get Lat & Long current location.
I'm getting no. of satellite from `locationManager.getAllProviders().size()` in `LocationListener`

I also tried

```
int satellite = 0;

GpsStatus status = locationManager.getGpsStatus(null);
            Iterable<GpsSatellite> sat = status.getSatellites();
            int i=0;
            while (sat.iterator().hasNext())
            {
                GpsSatellite gpsSatellite=(GpsSatellite)sats.iterator().next();

                if(gpsSatellite.usedInFix())
                {
                    satellite++;
                }


            }
```

but it showing me 0;

please help me.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: you can find help here:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359823/get-number-of-gps-fix-satellites

Comment: thanks but I seen it before and st=gpsStatus.getMaxSatellites() giving me 255 satellite.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the [GpsStatus](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.html) class methods.

You can use [getSatellies()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.html#getSatellites()) method to get a list of satellites. It is an [iterable](http://blog.dreasgrech.com/2010/03/javas-iterators-and-iterables.html) so you can traverse it and get the number of satellites.